# Simple Python to Check LIbraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, package, anaconda

I found this code somewhere which checks if there are some packages already installed.

```
# Python program that can be executed to report whether particular
# python packages are available on the system.

import os
import math
import sys

def test_numpy():
    try:
        import numpy as np
    except ImportError:
        print("Could not import numpy -> numpy failed")
        return None
    # Simple test
    a = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
    assert np.sum(a) == sum(a)
    print("-> numpy OK")


def test_scipy():
    try:
        import scipy
    except ImportError:
        print("Could not import 'scipy' -> scipy failed")
        return None
    # Simple test
    import scipy.integrate
    assert abs(scipy.integrate.quad(lambda x: x * x, 0, 6)[0] - 72.0) < 1e-6
    print("-> scipy OK")


def test_pylab():
    """Actually testing matplotlib, as pylab is part of matplotlib."""
    try:
        import pylab
    except ImportError:
            print("Could not import 'matplotlib/pylab' -> failed")
            return None
    # Creata plot for testing purposes
    xvalues = [i * 0.1 for i in range(100)]
    yvalues = [math.sin(x) for x in xvalues]
    pylab.plot(xvalues, yvalues, "-o", label="sin(x)")
    pylab.legend()
    pylab.xlabel('x')
    testfilename='pylab-testfigure.png'

    # check that file does not exist yet:
    if os.path.exists(testfilename):
        print("Skipping plotting to file as file {} exists already."\
            .format(testfilename))
    else:
        # Write plot to file
        pylab.savefig(testfilename)
        # Then check that file exists
        assert os.path.exists(testfilename)
        print("-> pylab OK")
        os.remove(testfilename)


def test_sympy():
    try:
        import sympy
    except ImportError:
            print("Could not import 'sympy' -> fail")
            return None
    # simple test
    x = sympy.Symbol('x')
    my_f = x ** 2
    assert sympy.diff(my_f,x) == 2 * x
    print("-> sympy OK")


def test_pytest():
    try:
        import pytest
    except ImportError:
            print("Could not import 'pytest' -> fail")
            return None
    print("-> pytest OK")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Running using Python {}".format(sys.version))

    print("Testing numpy...     "),
    test_numpy()

    print("Testing scipy...     "),
    test_scipy()

    print("Testing matplotlib..."),
    test_pylab()

    print("Testing sympy...     "),
    test_sympy()

    print("Testing pytest...    "),
    test_pytest()
```

I don't understand why are there tests ?

Without tests also we can assert that the libraries are there as no exceptions were thrown, right ?

Can I remove the tests and expect the correct results regarding package installations ?

Like:

```
def test_numpy():
        try:
            import numpy as np
        except ImportError:
            print("Could not import numpy -> numpy failed")
            return None
```

Also, is this test supposed to work in every kind of python distribution like anaconda etc ?

Does this depend upon the version of python I am using?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'd guess that the extra steps are there to guard against you doing something like having a file `numpy.py` that interferes with the import, or something being installed incorrectly.

Comment: What this set of tests does is check all the dependencies in one shot instead of failing after the first library isn't found. IMO, there's no need for the tests.